# Azure DataLake (ADLS) BulkDownload Bad Request

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-data-lake

I am trying to download the file from adls using the BulkDownload method using [BulkDownload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.datalake.store.adlsclient.bulkdownload?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_DataLake_Store_AdlsClient_BulkDownload_System_String_System_String_System_Int32_Microsoft_Azure_DataLake_Store_IfExists_System_IProgress_Microsoft_Azure_DataLake_Store_FileTransfer_TransferStatus__System_Boolean_System_Boolean_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) but I am getting a BAD Request response as below:

```
Error in getting metadata for path cc- 
adl://testaccount.azuredatalakestore.net//HelloWorld//test.txt
Operation: GETFILESTATUS failed with HttpStatus:BadRequest Error: Uexpected 
error in JSON parsing.
Last encountered exception thrown after 1 tries. [Uexpected error in JSON 
parsing]
[ServerRequestId:]
```

However, if I try to download the file through azure client shell it works.

I am using the [BulkDownload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.datalake.store.adlsclient.bulkdownload?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_DataLake_Store_AdlsClient_BulkDownload_System_String_System_String_System_Int32_Microsoft_Azure_DataLake_Store_IfExists_System_IProgress_Microsoft_Azure_DataLake_Store_FileTransfer_TransferStatus__System_Boolean_System_Boolean_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) as follow:

```
        client.BulkDownload(
            srcPath,
            dstPath);
```

Is anyone else facing the same issue for [BulkDownload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.datalake.store.adlsclient.bulkdownload?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_DataLake_Store_AdlsClient_BulkDownload_System_String_System_String_System_Int32_Microsoft_Azure_DataLake_Store_IfExists_System_IProgress_Microsoft_Azure_DataLake_Store_FileTransfer_TransferStatus__System_Boolean_System_Boolean_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this fixed as the srcPath is the relative path ("*/HelloWorld/test.txt*") in the azure datalake storage, previously I was the using the absolute path ("*adl://testaccount.azuredatalakestore.net//HelloWorld/test.txt*).